# Flex align a image to the rightmost of the HGroup?

Tags: apache-flex, alignment

- Is there a way to align an image to the rightmost of HGroup, which is setted to 100% width ?

here is my code, but it aligning the image "imageZoom" just after the object before it :

```
<s:VGroup id="masterVGroup" width="100%">
        <s:HGroup id="masterHGroup" gap="3" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">

            <s:SpriteVisualElement id="colorBox" width="12" height="6""/>

            <s:Label id="labelDisplay" text="delete"/>

            <s:Image id="imageZoom" 
                     right="2"
                     horizontalAlign="right"
                     source="{iconZOOM}"/>

        </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<s:VGroup id="masterVGroup" width="100%">
        <s:HGroup id="masterHGroup" gap="3" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="right">

            <s:SpriteVisualElement id="colorBox" width="12" height="6""/>

            <s:Label id="labelDisplay" text="delete"/>

            <s:Image id="imageZoom" 
                     right="2"
                     horizontalAlign="right"
                     source="{iconZOOM}"/>

        </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

I think it should work :)

In a case you want to have `SpriteVisualElement` and `Label` instances on the same places you can use spacer:

```
<s:VGroup id="masterVGroup" width="100%">
        <s:HGroup id="masterHGroup" gap="3" width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">

            <s:SpriteVisualElement id="colorBox" width="12" height="6""/>

            <s:Label id="labelDisplay" text="delete"/>

            <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>

            <s:Image id="imageZoom" 
                     right="2"
                     horizontalAlign="right"
                     source="{iconZOOM}"/>

        </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```